# firebase functions updating firestore document map field onWrite trigger is only working for last index

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Made a cloud function which will send email of invitation and upon successful send it will update a map object field but for some reason it is only working for the last object not all of them

**Function Code**

```
exports.sendInvitationEmailForMembers = functions.firestore
  .document("/organization-members/{OMid}")
  .onWrite(async (snap, context) => {
    if (snap.after.data() === undefined) {
      return null;
    }
    let authData = nodeMailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: SENDER_EMAIL,
        pass: SENDER_PASSWORD,
      },
    });
    // Exit when the data is deleted.
    const id = context.params.OMid;
    const afterData = snap.after.data();
    const db = admin.firestore();
    for (var prop in afterData) {
      if (afterData[prop].status === "invited") {
        const email = afterData[prop].email;
        const name = afterData[prop].fullName;

        authData
          .sendMail({
            from: "info@smallworldmusic.com",
            to: `${email}`,
            subject: "Organization Team Invitation",
            text: `Dear ${name}, you have been invited to join the team of 'organization name', please click on the following link to sign up and join. <br> http://localhost:3000/`,
            html: `Dear ${name}, you have been invited to join the team of 'organization name', please click on the following link to sign up and join. <br> http://localhost:3000/`,
          })
          .then(() => {
            db.collection("organization-members")
              .doc(id)
              .update({ [[prop] + ".status"]: "pending" })
              .then(() => {
                console.log("Successfully updated");
              })
              .catch(() => {
                console.log("Error occured while updating invitation status");
              });
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
      }
    }
  });
```

Notice that only last object status was changed but it should've changed the whole document objects statuses

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of small problems with the code as it is. These include:

- Your `onWrite` function is self-triggered. Each time you send an email, you currently update the document with the send status for that email - however this means that invites are sent again to those which haven't yet had their status updated. This means that in the worst case scenario, if you had `N` recipients - each of those users could get sent your invite email up to `N` times.
- In a similar vein, if a call to `sendMail` fails, it will be reattempted every time the document updates. If one particular email were to fail consistently, you may end up in an infinite loop. This can be mitigated by setting a `"failed"` status.
- Your GMail authentication details appear to be in your code. Consider using [Environment Configurations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) for this.
- Your function is connecting to GMail to send the emails, even if there are no emails to be sent.
- Use `console.log` and `console.error` as appropriate so they are shown properly in the Cloud Functions logs. Such as logging why a function ended.
- The `text` property of the email should not contain HTML like `<br>`

```
exports.sendInvitationEmailForMembers = functions.firestore
  .document("/organization-members/{OMid}")
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    // If deleted, cancel
    if (!change.after.exists) {
      console.log("Document deleted. Cancelling function.");
      return null;
    }
    
    const OMid = context.params.OMid; // keep parameter names consistent.
    const data = change.after.data();
    
    const pendingInvitations = [];
    for (const index in data) {
      if (data[index].status === "invited") {
        // collect needed information
        pendingInvitations.push({
          email: data.email,
          fullName: data.fullName,
          index
        });
        
        // alternatively: pendingInvitations.push({ ...data[index], index });
      }
    }
    
    // If no invites needed, cancel
    if (pendingInvitations.length == 0) {
      console.log("No invitations to be sent. Cancelling function.");
      return null;
    }
    
    // WARNING: Gmail has a sending limit of 500 emails per day.
    // See also: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126
    
    // Create transport to send emails
    const transport = nodeMailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: SENDER_EMAIL, // Suggestion: Use `functions.config()`, see above
        pass: SENDER_PASSWORD,
      },
    });
    
    // Create an object to store all the status changes
    const pendingDocUpdate = {};
    
    // For each invitation, attempt to send the email, and stash the result in `pendingDocUpdate`.
    // Wait until all emails have been sent.
    await Promise.all(pendingInvitations.map((invitee) => {
      return transport
          .sendMail({
            from: "info@smallworldmusic.com", // shouldn't this be SENDER_EMAIL?
            to: `${invitee.email}`,
            subject: "Organization Team Invitation",
            text: `Dear ${invitee.name}, you have been invited to join the team of 'organization name', please visit this link to sign up and join. http://localhost:3000/`,
            html: `Dear ${invitee.name}, you have been invited to join the team of 'organization name', please click on the following link to sign up and join. <br> http://localhost:3000/`,
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log(`Sent invite to ${invitee.email}.`);
            pendingDocUpdate[`${invitee.index}.status`] = "pending";
          }, (err) => {
            console.error(`Failed to invite ${invitee.email}.`, err);
            pendingDocUpdate[`${invitee.index}.status`] = "failed"; // save failure, so that emails are not spammed at the invitee
          });
    }));
    
    // Update the document with the changes
    return admin.firestore()
      .doc(`/organization-members/${OMid}`)
      .update(pendingUpdates)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Applied invitation status changes successfully. Finished.')
      }, (err) => {
        console.error('Error occured while updating invitation statuses.', err);
      });
  });
```

Comment: That’s a nice answer @samthecodingman! If I may it would be interesting to  explain in more detail why you use Promise.all and why you return a Promise at the end. Those key points about managing the life cycle properly are as important as the other corrections.

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec, I knew I missed something in the list at the top and decided to come back to it later with fresh eyes after staring blankly at it for a few minutes.

Comment: OMG. thank you so much for this detailed answer. i was struggling with logic and your answer just nailed it. thank you so much for correcting and making me understand
just change the last firestore update(pendingUpdates) to update(pendingDocUpdates)